# How do you select a column of a specific table when you escape the names with quotes?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do you select a column of a specific table when you escape the names with quotes? The following doesn't work:

```
SELECT "UnitTest1.Name" FROM "UnitTest1" WHERE "Name" = 'One';
```

It works if I remove the table name from the selected column, but that's not what I want because I plan to include a second table later which might share a column name or two.

The error I'm getting:

> ERROR:  column "UnitTest1.Name" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT
>   "UnitTest1.Name" FROM "UnitTest1" WHERE "Name" = 'One...
>                  ^
>
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: column "UnitTest1.Name" does not exist SQL state: 42703
>   Character: 8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quotes protect an identifier from being parsed, so the query fails, since you don't have a column called `"UnitTest1.Name"`. These are two identifiers (a table name and a column name), which need to be quoted separately:

```
SELECT "UnitTest1"."Name" FROM "UnitTest1" WHERE "Name" = 'One';
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrap in separate double quotes for both tablename and columnname, this should work fine

```
SELECT "UnitTest1"."Name" FROM "UnitTest1" WHERE "Name" = 'One';
```